# How to deal with 6 megabytes limit in AWS lambda services?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a three-tier app running in AWS. The midware was written in Python Flask and stored on a Linux machine.

However, they asked me to move to AWS Lambda services. There is a limit of 6 M for the returning data function. As I´m dealing with GEOJson, sometimes it´s necessary to return up to 15 M.

Despite the AWS lambda stuff is stateless, I could provide some way to return data partitioned, but it´s problematic I think it will be necessary to generate the whole map again and again until I could fulfill all data.

Is there a better way to deal with this? I´m programming in Python.

Answer (score 9):

I'd handle this by sending the data to S3, and issuing a redirect or JSON response that points to the URL on S3 (with [a temporary, expiring URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) if the data should be secure). If the data's long-lived, you can just leave it there; if not, you could use S3's [lifecycle rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to have the files automatically delete after 24 hours or so.

Comment: I thought in something like that, but it seems to me to be a little weird, that is, save something on disk to return results of a function call.

Comment: It's hardly uncommon to generate a temporary file on-disk for this sort of thing (it's just usually a *local* disk), and Lambda to S3 transfer times for a 15MB file should be easily under a second.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the answer! I was confused whether there is an upper limit to the file size that is written to s3 by lambda? I could not find any details regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the client too that receives those data, you can send a compressed result that is then uncompressed client side. So you'll be able to send that 15MB response too, which can become really small when compressed.

Or you can send a fragment of the whole response with a token or something indicating the client that the response is not complete. Than the client will make another request with that token to get the next fragment, and so on until there are no more fragments. At this point the client can join all fragments to get the full response.

Speaking of the 6MB limit, I hope that at some point we will have the ability to set what is the max payload size. since 6MB is fine for most cases, but not ALL cases

Comment: I think I'll implement the idea of a token. The drawback is that it takes an effort to get data from the database, and it will be necessary to repeat the sql sentences. I think Amazon could ask us more money if we need greater payload size.

Comment: Well, Lambda costs are now ridiculous, so I won't bother a small raise to get a bigger payload. The best case would be a setting in the Lambda function, so you'll pay for what you actually use, like the RAM amount

Answer (score 0):

You can use presigned S3 URL to upload, using this there will be no bound by payload size.

1. Get HTTP GET request to API Gateway, then Lambda function get generate presigned URL and return it presigned S3 URL.
2. Then client directly update content to s3 using pre-signed s3 URL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html